# Spring Boot with Apache Camel and Active MQ and Hawtio issue

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic, hawtio

Issue with Camel Routes being registered when hawtio is added as dependency and management port is configured.

Description:

1. Built a Spring Boot, Camel and Active MQ app.
2. The routes get registered when hawtio dependency is not included.
3. The routes are not registered when hawtio dependency is added and management port is configured.

Please find attached the pom.xml and application.yml configuration

Your help and guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
pom.xml


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bottomline.cbe</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-activemq</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz2</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Begin hawtio dependancies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--End hawtio dependancies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


application.yml:

server:
  port: 8091
  servlet:
        contextPath: /spring-boot-activemq

spring:
  activemq:
    broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
    user: admin
    password: admin


management:
  server:
    port: 9091
    servlet:
      context-path: /spring-boot-activemq-health
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: ["configprops", "env", "health", "info", "threaddump", "logfile", "hawtio", "jolokia"]
      base-path: /
      path-mapping:
        hawtio: /hawtio/console

endpoints:
  jolokia:
    sensitive: false

hawtio:
    authenticationEnabled: false
    offline: true

camel:
  springboot:
    name: spring-boot-activemq


JMS Config:
@Configuration
public class JMSConfig {

    String BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616"; 
    String BROKER_USERNAME = "admin"; 
    String BROKER_PASSWORD = "admin";

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(BROKER_URL);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(BROKER_USERNAME);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(BROKER_PASSWORD);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name="activemq")
    public ActiveMQComponent camelActiveMQComponent(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
        activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return activeMQComponent;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        return factory;
    }
}


Camel Routes:
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CamelRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("quartz2://testTimer?cron=0/1+5+*+?+*+*&job.name=REAL_TIME_test_JOB").routeId("test_REALTIME_QUARTZ_KICK_OFF").id("hello").log("Invoked test-Realtime job.")
        .to("activemq:diistransactions");
    }

}

Listener:
@JmsListener(destination = "diistransactions")
    @SendTo("outbounddiis")
    public String receiveMessage(final Message jsonMessage) throws JMSException {
        String messageData = null;
        String response = null;
        System.out.println("REceived message ::"+jsonMessage);
        if(jsonMessage instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)jsonMessage;
            messageData = textMessage.getText();
            response  = messageData;
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Expected Results:

```
2019-02-12 15:59:10.267  INFO 66428 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Route: hello started and consuming from: quartz2://testTimer?cron=0%2F1+5+*+%3F+*+*&job.name=REAL_TIME_test_JOB
2019-02-12 15:59:10.267  INFO 66428 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
```

Actual Results:

```
2019-02-12 16:00:06.741  INFO 56352 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started
```

Comment: Make sure to use the same Camel version, you are mixing different versions together.

Comment: You are adding dependencies to spring-boot-starter-activemq twice. Once without excluding the broker